# Can i upload old Ps1-Ps2-PSP saves into PS Plus account?

Tags: ps3, psn, ps2, psp, ps1

i managed to keep my old Ps1-Ps2-PSP saves into my Ps3 thanks to an official memory card adapter that sony made, but can i upload those saves into my PS account if i suscribe to PS Plus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. But...

I guess there are some cases where you can via a technicality though... At best you can migrate the save file to a PS Vita if that game is also available for the system, then backup the game on the Vita to the cloud (which should keep the virtual memory cards bound with it).